# Raspberry Pi ---- Reading Rockwell .dbf files

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, dbf

I am working with a Raspberry Pi using latest Raspbian Stretch with desktop to pull in `.dbf` files from a Rockwell PLC.
I ran

```
sudo apt-get updates
sudo apt-get upgrade
pip install dbfread
```

with no errors .

Attempting to read the .dbf files but cannot get past the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/TimeRiteMst/DBF.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dbfread import DBF
ImportError: No module named 'dbfread'
```

In reading https://pypi.org/project/dbfread/ and https://dbfread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

This should work with Python 3:

```
from dbfread import DBF

for record in DBF('/home/pi/test.DBF'):
    print(record)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
python -m pip install --user dbfread
python <your-script.py>
```

The goal is to use the same Python interpreter for both commands.

Comment: Thanks  -- this answers the question